# PHP, MYSQL, FOREACH check if same value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, loops, foreach

**Example:**

Mysql - table_data

```
  dataid   dataname    datastatus
    1        joel          1
    1        joelle        2
    1        joe           3
    1        joela         4
    1        joella        5
```

PHP

```
 $names = array('joel','joelle','joe','joela');
 foreach($names as $name)
 {
    $qcheck = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE dataname=".$name."");
     //Do checking here
 }
```

How can I know if joel, joelle,joe and joela datastatus are all same and not same?

How can I know the output of that example.. the output should be false because all of the status are not same, and In case all of the status are the same how can I know that?

Hope someone could help me thanks in advance..

Comment: are you using codeigniter??

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to do...

Comment: Why not fetch all together? `dataname IN ('joel','joelle','joe','joela') GROUP BY (datastatus)`. If you get a single row then same else different.

Comment: @barbarity I'm trying detect if all datastatus are all same using foreach

Comment: You could only `SELECT COUNT(datastatus)` and use `GROUP BY` to group the selected entries by the status and then count the different statuus

Comment: Im trying to detect if the user selected dataname has same datastatus and I also want to know if it doesn't have same datastatus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this optimized logic:

```
$namesStr = implode(',', $names);
$qcheck = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT datastatus) AS dataCount FROM table_data WHERE dataname IN($namesStr)");
$allSame = FALSE;
if ($qcheck->num_rows() >  0) {
    if ($qcheck->row()->dataCount == 1) {
        $allSame = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query like below.

```
$namesStr = "'" . implode("','", $names) . "'";
$qcheck = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT datastatus) AS dataCount FROM table_data WHERE dataname IN ($namesStr)");
```

Your query will look like...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT datastatus) AS dataCount FROM table_data WHERE dataname IN ('joel','joelle','joe','joela')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$names = array('joel','joelle','joe','joela');
$qcheck = $this->db->query("SELECT datastatus FROM table_data WHERE dataname=".$name."")->result_array;
foreach($names as $name)
{
    if(in_array($name,$qcheck)){
        //name exists
    } else {
        //name doesnot exists
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

Don't need to `implode array`. Just pass array in `where_in` like this-

```
        $names = array('joel','joelle','joe','joela');
        $this->db->select("COUNT(DISTINCT datastatus) AS dataCount");
        $this->db->from("table_data");
        $this->db->where_in('dataname',$names);
        $q=$this->db->get();

        if($q->num_rows() >  0){
            $result=$q->row();

            if ($result->dataCount == 1) {
                echo "true";
            }
        }
```